# Showing only the rows for the exact match (CSV with PHP) and having a message just once for a while loop in case of no match

Tags: php, csv, search, while-loop

I have a CSV file with three columns (Names, CAS number, and storage) as seen here [CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC2RU.png). I have been trying to search it for either a specific reagent name or CAS number, and show only rows 1 and 2. It is working, but when searching for a name that is also part of other reagents' names, it shows all the matches instead of displaying only the specific result for the exact searched word.

E.g. While searching for "1H-Indazole", it is shown as:

> CAS: 271-44-3 | Rotavap Cabinet, compartment AM-134
>
> CAS: 40598-94-5 | Freezer - Small flasks, compartment AM-176
>
> CAS: 53857-57-1 | Rotavap Cabinet, compartment AM-177

I would like to see only the first one "CAS: 271-44-3 | Rotavap Cabinet, compartment AM-134" for "1H-Indazole". For "$searchfor = "271-44-3";", it works like a charm!

```
$ch = fopen("QHeTem2023.csv", "r");
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);
$searchfor = "1H-Indazole";
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/mi";
while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {
if (preg_match($pattern, implode('', $row))) {
echo '\<div\> CAS: '.$row\[1\].' | '.$row\[2\].'\</div\>';
}
}
```

Additionally, if no match is found, I would like to echo "This reagent is not registered in our storage!". Multiple message instances appear if else {echo "message";} is placed within the while loop.

How could I address these issues?

Comment: The problem is clear, the Names column contains not only `1H-Indazole`, but also `3-Bromo-1H-indazole`, and your (case-insenstive) pattern you created for the search term `1H-Indazole` matches that as well.

Comment: And the fact that you are simply concatenating the content of all columns together to search only once in that full string, isn't all too helpful here either. I would rewrite this so that it searches column for column, separately. And then when you search the Names column, explode the content of that at `semicolon-space` first.

Comment: If you were only looking for full matches (your search term will alway be a full name, and not just part of it), you could then simply use `in_array` to check if one of those names matches; if you want partial matches as well, you will have to loop over that array and check each name for whether it _contains_ your search phrase.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you very much for all your comments. I have considered a case-insensitive pattern because the user may type 1H-indazole instead of 1H-Indazole. I do want partial matches, and I will try to apply your suggestion to search column for column followed by the use of explode. I will post an update If I succeed.